# How to fill radial array with gradient?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, gradient

How to fill radial array elements with gradient like this:

[image]

No idea how to make it happen automatically, rather than element by element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the flat pieces of the star. Make certain they are a compound shape by selecting them all and choosing `Object > Compound Path > Make` from the menu. (It doesn't matter what color they are.)

Now draw a circle which crosses roughly at the center of the shapes.

[image: circle]

Change the stroke to be a gradient and very thick. Thick enough so all your shapes fall *within* the stroke's boundaries. And move it behind the shapes. You may need to rotate the circle itself so the gradient will start/stop between two of the shapes.

[image: stroke]

Select the shapes and the stroke and choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Make`.

[image: final]

<sub>(Note gradient strokes requires Illustrator CS6 or better.)</sub>

Comment: Very close, except that gradient is visible on single element.

Comment: Not sure what that means. You can edit the gradient at any time. The gradient is visible on **all elements** it is merely more subtle on the other shapes. --> http://i.stack.imgur.com/6kGjw.png <-- if you want a different gradient, then make a different gradient.

Comment: I mean each element to have solid color instead of gradient. But all elements together form discrete gradient.

Comment: In that case, just fill each shape with a color tint. If that's all you want, you are over-thinking it.

Comment: It's simple example. More complex wheel consisting of ~30 elements. Doing that manually once is ok, but if need to be changed, it's hassle. With that said, I think your method is good when there are many thin shapes, so gradient will be barely noticeable.

Comment: You only have to do it once, then use `Edit > Edit Colors > Recolor Artwork` if you need to change colors.

Comment: ok ok, you are right :)

Comment: Another option -- Do it once in greyscale. Then Group and add a new solid color fill to the group via the Appearance panel and set the color fill's blend mode to Hue or Color. That way you merely need to change the flat color fill, the greyscale base will remain.

Answer (score 2):

You can script this sort of action with the [scripting abilities built into Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html). It's not the most clear documentation, but it is quite powerful.

The ExtendScript Toolkit is an easy way to edit and test code on the fly rather than using a text editor and running with the `File > Scripts > Run Script...` Menu.

In your case, if the objects are ordered in your layer by their degree (clockwise or counter-), you can run through the array `activeDocument.selection` and change each item's `fillColor` property. I believe that you'll need to change each channel separately. You can either code-in the color values or interpolate between the first and last object's fillColors.

If you have a set of all blue (255, 0, 0) RGBColor objects, run:

```
// Setup your variables
var doc = activeDocument;
var sel = doc.selection;
var len = sel.length;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    sel[i].fillColor.red += ( ( 255 / len ) * i );
     sel[i].fillColor.green += ( ( 255 / len ) * i );
}
```